# Use jq to remove top level module while retaining values

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to use jq in order to achieve the following -

With an input of:

```
{
    "SomeValue": {
        "x" : "y",
        "a" : "b"
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to remove 'SomeValue' and return just the key/values below so that my output would look like:

```
{
    "x" : "y",
    "a" : "b"
}
```

I've tried various permutations of commands I've seen on the forum but either end up deleting the whole structure or nothing at all - thanks in advance for any help/pointers in the right direction.

Comment: jq `.SomeValue` json ?

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the content of `.SomeValue`, that's already exactly your filter:

```
jq '.SomeValue'
```

If this part is nested deeper, and you want to update that part while keeping the rest, use the update operator `|=` with `.SomeValue` on that context (with your small sample this is still just `.`):

```bash
jq '. |= SomeValue'
```

Comment: This is too trivial a question to answer, please close it off with a relevant duplicate. No purpose in garnering points over questions like this

Comment: Thanks for your time and help @pmf, despite my attempts I couldn't find the solution so thankyou.